# Excel VBA Range returns empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do what I thought was going to be simple is turning out to be more difficult.  Basically what I am trying to do is populate a material column based upon the selection change of the cell next to it. The material column is a drop down menu which gets it's value from a LookUpRange.

Here is Part 1

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MaterialCellAddress As String
Dim MaterialCell As Range
Dim LookUpRangeName As String
Dim LookUpRange As Range

Select Case Target.Column
    Case 2
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        MsgBox ("Changing the width")
    Case 3
        MsgBox ("Changing the Height")
    Case 11

        MaterialCellAddress = "L" & Target.Row
        Set MaterialCell = Range(MaterialCellAddress)

        LookUpRangeName = "LookUpRange_" & Target.Value & "Materials"
        Set LookUpRange = Range(LookUpRangeName)

        Call LM.InitMaterialDropDownList(MaterialCell, LookUpRange)
    Case Else
        MsgBox ("Something else is going on")
 End Select
End Sub
```

And here is Part II inside the my LM Class

```
Public Sub InitMaterialDropDownList(ByVal MaterialCell As Range, ByVal LookUpRange As Range)
With Sheets("Entry Form").Range(MaterialCell).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=LookUpRange"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = "Select Edge Type"
.ErrorTitle = "Invalid Edge Type"
.InputMessage = "Select Edge Type"
.ErrorMessage = "You must select a valid edge type from the drop down list"
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

A couple things that I am noticing. When the code hits `Set MaterialCell = Range(MaterialCellAddress)` or this `Set LookUpRange = Range(LookUpRangeName)` both of these return empty for some reason.

And of course when I hit this...
`Call LM.InitMaterialDropDownList(MaterialCell, LookUpRange)`
it throws an object required error.

I'm not a vba veteran so I'm sure this is something stupid simple.  So I could use some help.

Comment: The code looks fine. Try to put a `MsgBox MaterialCellAddress` just after `MaterialCellAddress = "L" & Target.Row` and see what comes out. Hence, verify that the combination "letter+number" is the proper address of the range. Do the same with the name of the other range returning empty: at first glance, it doesn't seem there's a reason your code shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LM is a Class, Classes dont have subs or functions, instances of a Class have the functions/subs you define. so

```
Call LM.InitMaterialDropDownList(MaterialCell, LookUpRange)
```

should be

```
Call (new LM).InitMaterialDropDownList(MaterialCell, LookUpRange)
```

or shorter (Call is not neccessary)

```
(new LM).InitMaterialDropDownList MaterialCell, LookUpRange
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple.  Thanks for the help.